# Сервис для получения настроек почтового сервера

Tags: email, javamail

Скажите, есть ли сервис, через который можно получить настройки указанного почтового сервера (адрес imap, порт imap, адрес pop3, порт pop3, адрес smtp, порт smtp), к примеру для yandex ("imap.yandex.ru", "993".....)?

Answer (score 1):

Эта информация в принципе есть в онлайн хэлпе любого почтового сервиса. Однако, если необходимо получать необходимые настройки автоматически, то можно воспользоваться, например, [ISPDB](https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/) от Mozilla.

Правда, это единственная широко известная база данных настроек почтовых серверов с открытым доступом и она содержит данные только для серверов, которые хотя бы относительно популярны. Если же данный конкретный сервер широко известен, только в узких кругах, то надеяться остаётся только на его онлайн хэлп.

Comment: То что нужно)))))